# Is it required to have an alternate airport if you don't have a WAAS GPS?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules

I forgotten if an alternate is required if you don't have a WAAS GPS regardless of the 1-2-3 rule which states that 1 hour before and after ETA at your destination airport, the ceilings must be at least 2000' and 3 miles visibility. Must we file an alternate or is it dependent on the 1-2-3 rule? Which regulation talks about this because I can't find it.

Answer (score 6):

> FAR 91.167 -
>
> (a) No person may operate a civil aircraft in IFR conditions unless it carries enough fuel (considering weather reports and forecasts and weather conditions) to -
>
> (1) Complete the flight to the first airport of intended landing;
>
> (2) Except as provided in paragraph (b) of this section, fly from that airport to the alternate airport; and
>
> (3) Fly after that for 45 minutes at normal cruising speed or, for helicopters, fly after that for 30 minutes at normal cruising speed.
>
> (b) Paragraph (a)(2) of this section does not apply if:
>
> (1) Part 97 of this chapter prescribes a standard instrument approach procedure to, or a special instrument approach procedure has been issued by the Administrator to the operator for, the first airport of intended landing; and
>
> (2) Appropriate weather reports or weather forecasts, or a combination of them, indicate the following:
>
> (i) For aircraft other than helicopters. For at least 1 hour before and for 1 hour after the estimated time of arrival, the ceiling will be at least 2,000 feet above the airport elevation and the visibility will be at least 3 statute miles.

---

This regulation (91.167) applies to civil aircraft regardless of the equipment used for navigation (e.g. GPS/WAAS).

However, if your aircraft has a properly installed and operated GPS (see the TSO requirements in the AIM/AC references below) you can flight plan to your destination and alternate as follows:

1. TSO-C129() and TSO-C196() equipped (**GPS aircraft**) - Either the
   destination or alternate, but not both,  can offer only a GPS
   approach (no other type approaches need be available)
2. TSO -C145/-C146 (**WAAS Equipped Aircraft**) - Both the destination
   and the alternate can be airports with only GPS approaches
   available.

**References:** AIM 1-1-17 b 5 c/d, 1-1-18 c 9 a. **AND**
AC-105A, paragraph 9.5.1

Comment: When using WAAS at an alternate airport, flight planning must be based on flying the RNAV (GPS) LNAV or circling minima line, or minima on a GPS approach procedure, or conventional approach procedure with “or GPS” in the title.

Comment: Good comment, agreed.

Comment: @757toga you should edit that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the LNAV/VNAV minimums for flight planning purposes if are have approved baro-VNAV capabilities. (even if you are non-WAAS equipped). AIM 1-1-18)

Comment: Probably worth noting that very few general aviation piston aircraft have baro-VNAV equipment installed and (my understanding is) few transport category aircraft have WAAS GPS installed.